# php exec returns less results than entering into command line directly

Tags: php, linux, unix, grep

I have an exec command that is behaving differently than the same command given to linux through Penguinet.

```
 $res = exec('cd /mnt/mydirectory/; zcat log_file.gz');
 echo $res
```

When putting the commands directly into the command line, I see about 100 entries in the log file. However when I access the PHP page that has the `exec()` command, I see only 1. And it is formatted correctly. Why does PHP show me only one result? How can I make it show the entire contents of the file?

**EDIT:**

Seems this is only returning only the last line. How can I change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
exec('cd /mnt/mydirectory/; zcat log_file.gz', $res);
print_r($res);
```